# How to extract data from a ncfile

Tags: r, coordinates, data-retrieval

I am a newbee in R, so I need some assistance for extracting the values from a daily 7-year ncfile to match my dataframe with latitude, longitude and date. The problem is that I want the data for each geo-referenced point from the specific date that point was recorded. So the routine should be able to pick for each point the data for a specific date.
Thanks for your help,
Rui

Comment: Hi, it's easier to get help if you give us more details and some code. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.